# Flutter IOS push notification not working

Tags: iphone, flutter, firebase-notifications

In my Flutter application, the PUSH notifications are working for **Android** but for **IOS** I'm **not** getting the notification alert but it prints the notification in the console from onMessage method.

**Following is my command & output.**

> ```
> curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<API_KEY>" \
> --Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
> https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
> -d "{\"to\":\"<DEVICE_TOKEN>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Testing\"},\"priority\":10}"
> ```

**The output for IOS is:**

> {"multicast_id":9037043763539529381,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:158620223403259%62c34b3562c38b95"}]}

Following is the code block that gets executed when the notification received.

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onBackgroundMessage: null,
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    // app int he foreground
    print('This works on IOS and Android both');
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    // App is in the background
     print('This works on IOS and Android both');
    // But no notification alert shown to the user to click (android everything works fine)

  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    // app terminated
    print('This works on IOS and Android both');
    // But no notification alert shown to the user to click But no notification alert shown to the user to click (android everything works fine)
  },
);
```

Following is my Xcode image that shows the Push Notification capabilities are added.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the apn key from apple, follow [this](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1644#issuecomment-575594219) thread step by step.

Comment: I have made some progress so added that details too in the question. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I added This line in the "AppDelegate.swift" inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and it solved my issue:

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate }

// I found this in the documentation of the plugin, hopefully, it solves your issue!